# Showing that {0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5} is a group under addition modulo 6

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a set {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. What properties do I need to show to prove that it is a group under addition modulo 6? Any examples would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you know what the [group axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition) are?

Comment: You need to prove: 1) Existence of neutral element, 2) existence of simmetrical element, 3) The set is not empty, 4) Associative, 5) An element operated by other is in the set.

Comment: @manooooh the existence of an identity element might be thought to preclude the possibility that the set is empty